# Dojo: extracting data from view to plot a line graph in xpages

Tags: view, dojo, plot, xpages

I am trying to plot a line graph using dojo in xpages. I have a script library which contains code that takes values from my view called plots (the view contains values for time and temperature for x and y axis respectively in two different columns). I am trying to put these values into JSON and then extract them to plot the graph.

This part of the script library is supposed to get the values from the view into JSON

```
  var vw = database.getView('plots');
  var vwEntries = vw.getAllEntries();
  var Count = vwEntries.getCount();
  var vwEntry = vwEntries.getFirstEntry();

 var plot_temp = vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(1);
 var plot_time = vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(2);

  for (var x=1; x < vwCount; x++){

      var vwEntry = vwEntries.getNextEntry(vwEntry);
      plot_temp = plot_temp+","+vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(1);
      plot_time = plot_time+","+vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(2);
  }      

 getComponent("extracted_temp").setValue("["+plot_temp+"]");
 getComponent("extracted_time").setValue("["+plot_time+"]");
```

The rest of the script library contains code that plots the graph but I am not sure what command to use to use to plot the JSON values.

So far it's not working. This is how I tried to plot the graph. It doesn't work.

`chart1.addSeries("Series 1", [ vw ], {stroke: {color: "green"}});`

I also have a div on the page that specifies the size of the plot.

I have tried to use D3 and jqplot but I found that dojo might be the easiest one to use. I can plot the data if I hardcode it but not from a view. I am having problems with extracting the data from the view and putting into a graph. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us what the data in vw looks like ?

Comment: Perhaps the variable "vwCount" is not getting set correctly since you use "Count" in the initializer... I also recommend interating on the (vwEntry != null) so you have only one set of code..

Answer (score 0):

There are a few more graphic libraries you can try :-)

There is a ready to use [custom control on openNTF](http://www.openntf.org/Internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=YouAtNotes%20xCharting) for Dojo graphics. You can start with that one.

The repeating problem you seem to face is how to get the backend data into the front-end JavaScript. Once you have mastered that, you can use ANY library. There are 2 approaches ALL libraries provide: "static" values (what you use when you hardcode) or Ajax lookups.

Here are the steps you should take:

1. Create a static graphic you want to see in a custom control - make sure it works fine
2. Move the JS code you just have static on the page into an xp:outputScript control (static is fine) - make sure it works fine
3. Define all the values you want to vary (core data, labels or whatever) in the custom control properties as variables. E.g. data, xAxisLabel, yAxisLabel - define them as String!
4. On the page where you put the custom control enter values for your custom properties as static values
5. Now inside your outputScript tag replace your static values with the parameters - make sure it works fine. Sample:

**old** (your working code - whatever it is):

```
    var data = [{label : "test", value : 7}, {label : "x", value : 8}];
```

**new**:

```
    var data = #{compositeData.data};
```

Now test that. Your graph must show correctly - otherwise you missed/messed one step.

1. Final step: on the page replace the static values in your custom control property with whatever code you need to generate a String that look exactly like the static string you had entered.

There are more variations how to do that, the general idea is the combination of an outputScript tag with an #{EL} expression. Don't try all this in one go. Step by step with verification that the step worked. Otherwise you can't pinpoint where it failes.

Let us know how it goes

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I managed to extract data and I have a graph which plots data from a view. There are few issues with it though. It only extends as far as 12 points.

Comment: When you look at your page source in the browser: are all values there? If yes: problem in your Dojo. If no: problem with your extraction code

Comment: I think it is the extraction code. At the moment the situation is - I have set the field which contains the values for the x-axis to 0 (default value) when I extract the data, that field should become populated with extracted values from the view but for some reason it stays at a default value. But the odd thing is it plots a correct chart with the correct values on the x-axis. it's just not updating the field. very strange. When I change the default value it still says default as 0.

Comment: if you share your actual code instead of only describing it you might stand a chance someone pointing out the problem. And you should NOT use a field in the UI to transport the values to your JavaScript. Use a custom control property.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around the problem by using jqplot. I got my graph and didn't use dojo or script libraries. It plots a graph which is just as nice. I got the idea from  [this website](http://blog.wilhow.net/2013/03/17/charting-104-in-xpages-connecting-to-notes-document/)
. To get the code to plot the graph I needed I made some modifications to the extract code button and I combined extract data and replot button into one (by removing the partial update element ID) so the code looks like this

```
var viewPanel = getComponent("viewPanel1"); //in the view panel select the check box
var docIDArray = viewPanel.getSelectedIds(); //get that selected ID

for (i = 0; i < docIDArray.length; i++) {
var docId = docIDArray[i];
var doc = database.getDocumentByID(docId);
var moo = doc.getItemValue("LoggerID"); //selected ID is defined
var h = doc.getItemValue("G");
var e = doc.getItemValue("IE");
var f = doc.getItemValue("FF");
var c = doc.getItemValue("CH");
var s = doc.getItemValue("SA");
var o = doc.getItemValue("OP");
var l = doc.getItemValue("LM");

//comparing the entries to the selected ID and if found extracting the values for LoggerID

var vw = database.getView('BrowserStats'); //Get the Notesview
var vwEntries = vw.getAllEntries(); //Get handle of all entries
var vwCount = vwEntries.getCount(); //Get the Count to use as uBound
var vwEntry = vwEntries.getFirstEntry(); //Get first value

//Get the first entry and get the column value of the first entry

var plot_LoggerID = vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(2);
var plot_G = vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(5);    
var plot_IE = vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(6);    
var plot_FF = vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(7);    
var plot_CH = vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(8);    
var plot_SA = vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(9);
var plot_OP = vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(10);    
var plot_LM = vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(11);            

for (var x = 1; x < vwCount; x++) {
//    Looping through all the entries and collect the column values
vwEntry = vwEntries.getNextEntry(vwEntry);
plot_LoggerID = plot_LoggerID + "," + vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(2);
plot_G = plot_G + "," + vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(5);    
plot_IE = plot_IE + "," + vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(6);    
plot_FF = plot_FF + "," + vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(7);    
plot_CH = plot_CH + "," + vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(8);    
plot_SA = plot_SA + "," + vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(9);    
plot_OP = plot_OP + "," + vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(10);    
plot_LM = plot_LM + "," + vwEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(11);    

}

getComponent("extracted_LoggerID").setValue(moo);
getComponent("extracted_G").setValue(h);
getComponent("extracted_IE").setValue(e);    
getComponent("extracted_FF").setValue(f);    
getComponent("extracted_CH").setValue(c);    
getComponent("extracted_SA").setValue(s);    
getComponent("extracted_OP").setValue(o);   
getComponent("extracted_LM").setValue(l);       
}
```

The jqplot function was similar but with different data for my graph and I changed it to line graph too. Many thanks to Wil How!